# Finding $P\left(\frac{(Y+Z)^2}{(Y-Z)^2}<4\right)$ where $Y,Z\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be independent random variables

$Y\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

$Z\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

I would like to compute $P\left(\frac{Y^2+2YZ+Z^2}{Y^2-2YZ+Z^2}<4\right) = P\left(\frac{(Y+Z)^2}{(Y-Z)^2}<4\right)$

---

My attempt:

$P(\frac{Y^2+2YZ+Z^2}{Y^2-2YZ+Z^2}<4) = 1 - P(\frac{Y^2+2YZ+Z^2}{Y^2-2YZ+Z^2}\ge4)$

$= 1- \frac{\mu}{4}$

where $\mu= E[\frac{Y^2+2YZ+Z^2}{Y^2-2YZ+Z^2}] = \frac{E(Y^2+2YZ+Z^2)}{E(Y^2-2YZ+Z^2)}= \frac{E(Y^2)+2E(YZ)+E(Z^2)}{E(Y^2)-2E(YZ)+E(Z^2)} $

I cannot proceed this question further. How can I find this probability. Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about $X$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, it is typo. I corrected.

Comment: Identify the distribution of $(Y+Z)^2/(Y-Z)^2$.

Comment: How can I do? @StubbornAtom

Comment: I do not understand what you said. Can you please help me? @StubbornAtom

Comment: I suspect $E\left[\frac{Y^2+2YZ+Z^2}{Y^2-2YZ+Z^2}\right]$  is infinite.  It is certainly not  $\frac{E(Y^2+2YZ+Z^2)}{E(Y^2-2YZ+Z^2)}=1$

Comment: Well, as StubbornAtom suggested , how can we identify $(Y+Z)^2/(Y-Z)^2$ and solve from there? @Henry

Comment: Simulation would get you about $P\left(\frac{Y^2+2YZ+Z^2}{Y^2-2YZ+Z^2}<4\right) \approx 0.705$

Comment: How did you get this simulation result? Can we find it by hand? @Henry

Comment: I tried a million samples of $Y$ and $Z$ and then saw how many gave that ratio being below $4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=\frac{(Y+Z)^2}{(Y-Z)^2}$.

Now verify the following:

- $Y+Z\sim N(0,2\sigma^2)$ and $Y-Z \sim N(0,2\sigma^2)$ are independently distributed.
- $(Y+Z)^2\sim 2\sigma^2 \chi^2_1$ and $(Y-Z)^2\sim 2\sigma^2 \chi^2_1$ are independently distributed.
- $U$ is the ratio of two independent $\chi^2_1$ random variables.
- $U$ has an [F distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) with $(1,1)$ degrees of freedom, i.e. $U\sim F_{1,1}$.

Write down the density $f_U$ (say) of $U$. And find $P(U<4)=\int_{-\infty}^4 f_U(x)\,dx$.

---

Alternatively, if $T=\frac{Y+Z}{Y-Z}$, then it follows from the first bullet that $T$ has a standard Cauchy distribution with cdf $P(T<t)=\frac12+\frac1{\pi}\tan^{-1}(t)$. And you are asked to find $$P(T^2<4)=P(-2<T<2)=P(T<2)-P(T<-2)$$

Comment: Many thanks. Well, I look at the density function of F-distribution, the density is very complex. Is there any program which calculate this integration?

Comment: You didn't see the degrees of freedom. It's the simplest possible F density. You can do this by hand.

Comment: @1190 Check edit.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{(Y+Z)^2}{(Y-Z)^2}<4$ is equivalent to $3Y^2-10YZ+3Z^2>0$ or $(3Y-Z)(Y-3Z)>0$. Thus, we have
$$
P\left[\frac{(Y+Z)^2}{(Y-Z)^2}<4\right]=P\left[(3Y-Z)(Y-3Z)<0\right]=\int_{D}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-(y^2+z^2)/2\sigma^2}dydz,
$$
where $D=\{(y,z)\colon (3y-z)(y-3z)>0\}$. Can you continue now?

Comment: It is quite complex. Can you further do if it is possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

The command of Mathematica 13

```
Probability[(Y + Z)^2/(Y - Z)^2 < 4, {Y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], 
Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]]}]
```

results in $$\frac{\pi -\tan ^{-1}(3)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\pi }=0.704833\dots .$$
As we see, the result does not depend on $\sigma>0$.